# Set div height to all childs

Tags: jquery

I've a main div container called `tabs` (as id), in this I've another container called `divContent`, inside this I've a lot of tabs (as Chrome tab), this tabs are all an id as: tabs1, tabs2 etc..

this is the structure:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="divContent">
         <div id="tabs1"></div>
         <div id="tabs1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is possible set the height of all tabs inside `divContent`?

Comment: why use jQuery, why not just use css?

Comment: @Pete the height is dynamic by screen size

Comment: @JdoeE still don't need jquery to set the height, css is more than capable but as you have not created an [MCVE], it would be hard to show you

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just select them and set the height, for example:

```
$("#divContent > div").height(100);
```

Comment: Why set them all to `100px` height?

Answer (score 0):

To  set height of all selected tabs to `200px` say

```
 $("divContent").children("div").css("height","200px");
```

Comment: Why not `.height(200)`?

Comment: @eisbehr : why not the one which I did ?

Comment: Because it is overhead. You always have to use a string when setting the value. And it is mutch more to write for the same action. Even like `$("divContent").children("div")` is the same as `$("divContent > div")`, and it should be faster too, because you only make one select instead of two. So you do a lot more as needed imo. :) But I just wanted to ask if you got any reason for doing this ...

Comment: @eisbehr : what you said is accepted !  What I thought was if I write my code in this way then any user who is new to JQuery can understand the logic by just reading the code. For Eg :Code itself states that  I need to select all `children` of `.divContent` and then assign a css to it. So its a self explanatory code. But I accpet what you said is better.

Comment: @eisbehr `$("#divContent > div")` will be a slower call than using `.children` - jQuery will have to parse the selector and then all it does is call `.children` so if you are that bothered about overhead then you should keep the .children and not use what you suggested

Comment: Isn't `>` a standard css selector? Hmm. Now you got my attention. I will do a benchmark...

Comment: @eisbehr have a look at this to see why traditional css selectors are slower in jquery: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery--net-18052

Comment: No, but I was thinking that jQuery not pase default selectors and just execute them on the DOM. It really seems that is was wrong there. There is a very small difference in my benchmark, that `.children` (on 1.000.000 loops) is about 0.5s faster. But at least in my benchmak, `height` is faster than `css`. https://jsfiddle.net/1k1akqry/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have duplicate IDs. And that must be the reason you are not able to target them based on IDs. IDs should be always unique.You can rather use same class(say `divtabs`) and then target them using class selector:

```
$('.divtabs').height(500);
```

You can use immediate child selector to target immediate child div elements in `#divContent` div:

```
$('#divContent > div').height(500);
```

Also you can use attribute starts with selector if you want to target element that have IDs in pattern tabs1,tabs2...etc. :

```
$('#divContent  div[id^=tabs]').height(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Html - set class in inner div - id should be unique

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="divContent">
         <div id="tabs1" class="in-tab">aaa</div> 
         <div id="tabs2" class="in-tab">bbb</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $("#tabs").height();
  alert(height)
  $(".in-tab").css("height",height+"px")
});
```

Comment: Why not `.height(height)`?